# cmake run xxd as custom command

Tags: c++, cmake, embedded-resource

I've a `rc` directory I want to run `xxd -i filename` recursively in that directory.and add the generated files to my project.

I was checking some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395350/using-cmake-with-a-custom-file-generator) on lua. and I did it in a similar way.

```
SET(RESOURCE_COMPILER "xxd")
SET(COMPILED_RESOURCES "rc/base.css rc/common.js")
FOREACH(F ${COMPILED_RESOURCES})
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT "${COMPILED_RESOURCES}/${F}"
        COMMAND ${RESOURCE_COMPILER} -i "${COMPILED_RESOURCES}/${F}"
        COMMENT "Compiling ${F} to binary")
    LIST (APPEND COMPILED_RESOURCES "${COMPILED_RESOURCES}/${F}")
ENDFOREACH()
```

but I don't see any file generated at all.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons you may not be seeing the output files.  Your xxd command isn't well formed in the `add_custom_command`, but also the command will only be executed if the output file is required as a source in another CMake target (exe or lib) in the same CMakeLists.txt.

I'd change your snippet to something like:

```
SET(RESOURCE_COMPILER xxd)
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE COMPILED_RESOURCES "rc/*")
FOREACH(INPUT_FILE ${COMPILED_RESOURCES})
    SET(OUTPUT_FILE ${INPUT_FILE}.hex)
    ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(
        OUTPUT ${OUTPUT_FILE}
        COMMAND ${RESOURCE_COMPILER} -i ${INPUT_FILE} ${OUTPUT_FILE}
        COMMENT "Compiling ${INPUT_FILE} to binary")
    LIST(APPEND COMPILED_RESOURCES ${OUTPUT_FILE})
ENDFOREACH()
```

Then if you have another target which depends on the `${OUTPUT_FILE}`s the command will be executed when that target is being built:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(MY_EXE main.cc ${COMPILED_RESOURCES})
```

Comment: I put a MESSAGE inside the loop. I observed there is no space. but even after I fixed this with `${RESOURCE_COMPILER} " -i " ${INPUT_FILE}` there was no files generated.

Comment: Putting a `message` inside the loop won't give a proper impression of the command executed by `add_custom_command`.  The args are all passed individually to xxd with spaces added appropriately.  There should be no need to do `" -i "`.  If you want to check your command is well formed, you could temporarily add `execute_process(COMMAND ${RESOURCE_COMPILER} -i ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/rc/base.css ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/rc/base.css.hex)` to your CMakeLists.txt.  This will run every time cmake is invoked and will let you see if the command is doing what you want.

Comment: So should I replace `ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND` with `execute_process` ?

Comment: I would just add `execute_process` to test that your `COMMAND` arguments work OK, then remove it again.  `execute_process` will be invoked every time CMake is run, whereas your `add_custom_command` requires cmake to run, then also requires building a target that depends on the `OUTPUT` of the custom command before the actual custom command will be invoked.  It's just a quicker way to check that the `COMMAND` part is well formed and does as expected.

Comment: This was a life saver for me. Two things, you can use `find_program(RESOURCE_COMPILER xxd)` instead of `set` and change case to lowercase for cmake commands